# FreeRADIUS Perl Module "Unknown or invalid value "perl" for attribute Auth-Type"

Tags: centos, perl, freeradius

I am attempting to setup a FreeRadius Server with an OTP (LinOTP) backend in Centos 7. My issue is loading a perl module needed to link FreeRADIUS to LinOTP. No matter what I try I just keep getting the error below when I try starting radiusd (with "/usr/sbin/radiusd -C -lstdout -xx"):

```
/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize[46]: Parse error (check) for entry DEFAULT: Unknown or invalid value "perl" for attribute Auth-Type
Failed reading /etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize
/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files[9]: Instantiation failed for module "files"
```

per documentation I have completed the following:

-added "DEFAULT Auth-type := perl" as the first and only uncommented line in /etc/raddb/users

-added the module location to /etc/raddb/mods-available/perl

-added the Auth-Type declarations in the site file (/etc/raddb/sites-available/linotp) see below.

-I have also tried copying the changes over to the default site but I get the same issue.

Here are the contents of the relevant files with comments removed (these things are 99% comments)
/etc/raddb/users

```
DEFAULT         Auth-type := perl
```

/etc/raddb/mods-available/perl

```
perl {
        filename = /etc/raddb/mods-config/perl/radius_linotp.pm
}
```

/etc/raddb/sites-available/linotp

```
authorize {
        files
        perl
        if (ok || updated) {
                update control {
                        Auth-Type := Perl
                }
        }
        preprocess
        chap
        mschap
        suffix
        unix
        expiration
        logintime
        pap
}
authenticate {
perl
        Auth-Type Perl {
                perl
         }
}
preacct {
        preprocess
        acct_unique
        suffix
        files
}
accounting {
        perl
        detail
        unix
        radutmp
        attr_filter.accounting_response
}
session {
        radutmp
}
post-auth {
        exec
        Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
                attr_filter.access_reject
        }
}
pre-proxy {
}
post-proxy {
}
```

/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize

```
DEFAULT         Auth-type := perl
```

and finally the verbose startup log from running /usr/sbin/radiusd -C -lstdout -x

```
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.13
Copyright (C) 1999-2017 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
Starting - reading configuration files ...
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary.dhcp
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary.vqp
including dictionary file /etc/raddb/dictionary
including configuration file /etc/raddb/radiusd.conf
including configuration file /etc/raddb/proxy.conf
including configuration file /etc/raddb/clients.conf
including files in directory /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/cache_eap
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/chap
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/date
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/dhcp
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/digest
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/dynamic_clients
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/echo
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/exec
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/expiration
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/expr
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/linelog
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/logintime
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/mschap
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ntlm_auth
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/pap
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/passwd
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/preprocess
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/radutmp
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/replicate
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/soh
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/sradutmp
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/unix
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/unpack
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/utf8
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/perl
including files in directory /etc/raddb/policy.d/
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/accounting
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/canonicalization
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/control
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/cui
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/debug
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/dhcp
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/eap
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/filter
including configuration file /etc/raddb/policy.d/operator-name
including files in directory /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/
main {
 security {
        user = "radiusd"
        group = "radiusd"
        allow_core_dumps = no
 }
        name = "radiusd"
        prefix = "/usr"
        localstatedir = "/var"
        logdir = "/var/log/radius"
        run_dir = "/var/run/radiusd"
}
main {
        name = "radiusd"
        prefix = "/usr"
        localstatedir = "/var"
        sbindir = "/usr/sbin"
        logdir = "/var/log/radius"
        run_dir = "/var/run/radiusd"
        libdir = "/usr/lib64/freeradius"
        radacctdir = "/var/log/radius/radacct"
        hostname_lookups = no
        max_request_time = 30
        cleanup_delay = 5
        max_requests = 16384
        pidfile = "/var/run/radiusd/radiusd.pid"
        checkrad = "/usr/sbin/checkrad"
        debug_level = 0
        proxy_requests = yes
 log {
        stripped_names = no
        auth = no
        auth_badpass = no
        auth_goodpass = no
        colourise = yes
        msg_denied = "You are already logged in - access denied"
 }
 resources {
 }
 security {
        max_attributes = 200
        reject_delay = 1.000000
        status_server = yes
 }
}
radiusd: #### Loading Realms and Home Servers ####
 proxy server {
        retry_delay = 5
        retry_count = 3
        default_fallback = no
        dead_time = 120
        wake_all_if_all_dead = no
 }
 home_server localhost {
        ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
        port = 1812
        type = "auth"
        secret = <<< secret >>>
        response_window = 20.000000
        response_timeouts = 1
        max_outstanding = 65536
        zombie_period = 40
        status_check = "status-server"
        ping_interval = 30
        check_interval = 30
        check_timeout = 4
        num_answers_to_alive = 3
        revive_interval = 120
  limit {
        max_connections = 16
        max_requests = 0
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 0
  }
  coa {
        irt = 2
        mrt = 16
        mrc = 5
        mrd = 30
  }
 }
 home_server_pool my_auth_failover {
        type = fail-over
        home_server = localhost
 }
 realm example.com {
        auth_pool = my_auth_failover
 }
 realm LOCAL {
 }
radiusd: #### Loading Clients ####
 client localhost {
        ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
        require_message_authenticator = no
        secret = <<< secret >>>
        nas_type = "other"
        proto = "*"
  limit {
        max_connections = 16
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 30
  }
 }
 client localhost_ipv6 {
        ipv6addr = ::1
        require_message_authenticator = no
        secret = <<< secret >>>
  limit {
        max_connections = 16
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 30
  }
 }
Debugger not attached
radiusd: #### Instantiating modules ####
 modules {
  # Loaded module rlm_always
  # Loading module "reject" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always reject {
        rcode = "reject"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "fail" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always fail {
        rcode = "fail"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "ok" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always ok {
        rcode = "ok"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "handled" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always handled {
        rcode = "handled"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "invalid" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always invalid {
        rcode = "invalid"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "userlock" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always userlock {
        rcode = "userlock"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "notfound" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always notfound {
        rcode = "notfound"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "noop" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always noop {
        rcode = "noop"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "updated" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  always updated {
        rcode = "updated"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_attr_filter
  # Loading module "attr_filter.post-proxy" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.post-proxy {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/post-proxy"
        key = "%{Realm}"
        relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.pre-proxy" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.pre-proxy {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/pre-proxy"
        key = "%{Realm}"
        relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.access_reject" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.access_reject {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject"
        key = "%{User-Name}"
        relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.access_challenge" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.access_challenge {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_challenge"
        key = "%{User-Name}"
        relaxed = no
  }
  # Loading module "attr_filter.accounting_response" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
  attr_filter attr_filter.accounting_response {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/accounting_response"
        key = "%{User-Name}"
        relaxed = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_cache
  # Loading module "cache_eap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/cache_eap
  cache cache_eap {
        driver = "rlm_cache_rbtree"
        key = "%{%{control:State}:-%{%{reply:State}:-%{State}}}"
        ttl = 15
        max_entries = 0
        epoch = 0
        add_stats = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_chap
  # Loading module "chap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/chap
  # Loaded module rlm_date
  # Loading module "date" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/date
  date {
        format = "%b %e %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_detail
  # Loading module "detail" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail
  detail {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "auth_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail auth_log {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/auth-detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "reply_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail reply_log {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/reply-detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "pre_proxy_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail pre_proxy_log {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/pre-proxy-detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "post_proxy_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail post_proxy_log {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/post-proxy-detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_dhcp
  # Loading module "dhcp" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/dhcp
  # Loaded module rlm_digest
  # Loading module "digest" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/digest
  # Loaded module rlm_dynamic_clients
  # Loading module "dynamic_clients" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/dynamic_clients
  # Loaded module rlm_exec
  # Loading module "echo" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/echo
  exec echo {
        wait = yes
        program = "/bin/echo %{User-Name}"
        input_pairs = "request"
        output_pairs = "reply"
        shell_escape = yes
  }
  # Loading module "exec" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/exec
  exec {
        wait = no
        input_pairs = "request"
        shell_escape = yes
        timeout = 10
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_expiration
  # Loading module "expiration" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/expiration
  # Loaded module rlm_expr
  # Loading module "expr" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/expr
  expr {
        safe_characters = "@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-_: /äéöüàâæçèéêëîïôœùûüaÿÄÉÖÜßÀÂÆÇÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸ"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_files
  # Loading module "files" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files
  files {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize"
        acctusersfile = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/accounting"
        preproxy_usersfile = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/pre-proxy"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_linelog
  # Loading module "linelog" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/linelog
  linelog {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/linelog"
        escape_filenames = no
        syslog_severity = "info"
        permissions = 384
        format = "This is a log message for %{User-Name}"
        reference = "messages.%{%{reply:Packet-Type}:-default}"
  }
  # Loading module "log_accounting" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/linelog
  linelog log_accounting {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/linelog-accounting"
        escape_filenames = no
        syslog_severity = "info"
        permissions = 384
        format = ""
        reference = "Accounting-Request.%{%{Acct-Status-Type}:-unknown}"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_logintime
  # Loading module "logintime" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/logintime
  logintime {
        minimum_timeout = 60
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_mschap
  # Loading module "mschap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/mschap
  mschap {
        use_mppe = yes
        require_encryption = no
        require_strong = no
        with_ntdomain_hack = yes
   passchange {
   }
        allow_retry = yes
        winbind_retry_with_normalised_username = no
  }
  # Loading module "ntlm_auth" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ntlm_auth
  exec ntlm_auth {
        wait = yes
        program = "/path/to/ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --domain=MYDOMAIN --username=%{mschap:User-Name} --password=%{User-Password}"
        shell_escape = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_pap
  # Loading module "pap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/pap
  pap {
        normalise = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_passwd
  # Loading module "etc_passwd" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/passwd
  passwd etc_passwd {
        filename = "/etc/passwd"
        format = "*User-Name:Crypt-Password:"
        delimiter = ":"
        ignore_nislike = no
        ignore_empty = yes
        allow_multiple_keys = no
        hash_size = 100
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_preprocess
  # Loading module "preprocess" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/preprocess
  preprocess {
        huntgroups = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/preprocess/huntgroups"
        hints = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/preprocess/hints"
        with_ascend_hack = no
        ascend_channels_per_line = 23
        with_ntdomain_hack = no
        with_specialix_jetstream_hack = no
        with_cisco_vsa_hack = no
        with_alvarion_vsa_hack = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_radutmp
  # Loading module "radutmp" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/radutmp
  radutmp {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/radutmp"
        username = "%{User-Name}"
        case_sensitive = yes
        check_with_nas = yes
        permissions = 384
        caller_id = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_realm
  # Loading module "IPASS" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
  realm IPASS {
        format = "prefix"
        delimiter = "/"
        ignore_default = no
        ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loading module "suffix" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
  realm suffix {
        format = "suffix"
        delimiter = "@"
        ignore_default = no
        ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loading module "realmpercent" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
  realm realmpercent {
        format = "suffix"
        delimiter = "%"
        ignore_default = no
        ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loading module "ntdomain" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
  realm ntdomain {
        format = "prefix"
        delimiter = "\\"
        ignore_default = no
        ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_replicate
  # Loading module "replicate" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/replicate
  # Loaded module rlm_soh
  # Loading module "soh" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/soh
  soh {
        dhcp = yes
  }
  # Loading module "sradutmp" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/sradutmp
  radutmp sradutmp {
        filename = "/var/log/radius/sradutmp"
        username = "%{User-Name}"
        case_sensitive = yes
        check_with_nas = yes
        permissions = 420
        caller_id = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_unix
  # Loading module "unix" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/unix
  unix {
        radwtmp = "/var/log/radius/radwtmp"
  }
Creating attribute Unix-Group
  # Loaded module rlm_unpack
  # Loading module "unpack" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/unpack
  # Loaded module rlm_utf8
  # Loading module "utf8" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/utf8
  # Loaded module rlm_perl
  # Loading module "perl" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/perl
  perl {
        filename = "/etc/raddb/mods-config/perl/radius_linotp.pm"
        func_authorize = "authorize"
        func_authenticate = "authenticate"
        func_post_auth = "post_auth"
        func_accounting = "accounting"
        func_preacct = "preacct"
        func_checksimul = "checksimul"
        func_detach = "detach"
        func_xlat = "xlat"
        func_pre_proxy = "pre_proxy"
        func_post_proxy = "post_proxy"
        func_recv_coa = "recv_coa"
        func_send_coa = "send_coa"
  }
  instantiate {
  }
  # Instantiating module "reject" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "fail" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "ok" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "handled" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "invalid" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "userlock" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "notfound" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "noop" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "updated" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.post-proxy" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/post-proxy
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.pre-proxy" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/pre-proxy
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.access_reject" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject
[/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject]:11 Check item "FreeRADIUS-Response-Delay"    found in filter list for realm "DEFAULT". 
[/etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject]:11 Check item "FreeRADIUS-Response-Delay-USec"       found in filter list for realm "DEFAULT". 
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.access_challenge" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_challenge
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.accounting_response" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/accounting_response
  # Instantiating module "cache_eap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/cache_eap
rlm_cache (cache_eap): Driver rlm_cache_rbtree (module rlm_cache_rbtree) loaded and linked
  # Instantiating module "detail" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail
  # Instantiating module "auth_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
rlm_detail (auth_log): 'User-Password' suppressed, will not appear in detail output
  # Instantiating module "reply_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  # Instantiating module "pre_proxy_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  # Instantiating module "post_proxy_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  # Instantiating module "expiration" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/expiration
  # Instantiating module "files" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize
/etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize[46]: Parse error (check) for entry DEFAULT: Unknown or invalid value "perl" for attribute Auth-Type
Failed reading /etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize
/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files[9]: Instantiation failed for module "files"
```

From this I can see the perl module being loaded but it seems something is not happy about the Auth-Type.

Comment: Yeah 3.0.13 is years out of date.  Use the packages from packages.networkradius.com the issue may have already been fixed.

Comment: Or it could just be an instantiation order thing, in which case just add an auth-type value manually in the dictionary